# How to use a hash/dictionary in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, hash

Here is my code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

for lines in handle:
    if not lines.startswith("From ") : continue
    list = lines.split()
    #print list
    lst = list[1]
    lst = lst.split()
    print lst

counts = {}
names = lst
for words in names:
    if words not in counts:
        counts[words] = 1
    else:
        counts[words] = counts[words] + 1
    print counts
```

I'm trying to learn Python.

When it comes to transfering the lst array into a hash/dictionary, I try to test it by printing the dictionary. I get the last line, {'cwen@iupui.edu': 1} when clearly if I wrote the code correctly I would have a dictionary and count of all these email addressed tallied. Can someone point out where my code is breaking?

Thank you.

Comment: Please sanitize your data, I don't think people would like to have their emails everywhere.

Comment: the reason it is not working is because you are replacing the list rather than adding new elements. at the end, it will use whatever you replaced it with last.

Comment: The coursework is from University of Michigan, Dr. Charles Severance. All his material is open for free use as long as credit is given. So here is the credit. :)

Comment: Would you provide a link to the material please? I'll have to contact the moderators to destroy this personal data if we cannot be sure the above data is in the public domain (this approach to privacy is common practice on Stack Overflow).

Comment: coursera.org - programming for everybody python, Dr. Charles Severance. Try emailing him IMO.

Comment: i'll take out the output until it can be confirmed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `for` loop where you are creating `lst` , it is creating a new `lst` for each element. And hence, `lst` at the end only has the last email `id` not all of them.

Change it to something like -

```
lst = []
for lines in handle:
    if not lines.startswith("From ") : continue
    list1 = lines.split()
    #print list
    elem1 = list1[1]
    lst.append(elem1)
    print lst
```

Also, you should not use `list` as the name of a variable , it will shadow the builtin function `list` .

---

Also, for your second case, you should not re-invent the wheel, you can simple use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)  , Example -

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(lst)
```

Comment: Thank everyone for their input. I will look at it later with your comments in mind.

Comment: I substituted your code and I get a print out of every individual letter. T-T Do I have to add all the indexes of the arrays to actually consolidate everything?

Comment: Made a small change, changed from `lst.extend()` to `lst.append()` , check now.

Comment: update* I fixed it by replacing .extend with .append! The first part is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

After this loop

```
for lines in handle:
    if not lines.startswith("From ") : continue
    list = lines.split()
    #print list
    lst = list[1]
    lst = lst.split()
    print lst
```

`lst` will just contain the last entry. You need to save them somewhere to make your program work.

You can start by using a list comprehension instead of the entire first loop

```
lst = [line.split()[1] for line in fin if line.startswith("From ")]
```

Then use `Counter` to count the entries. I have also switched to using a generator expression here

```
from collections import Counter
fname = raw_input("Enter file:")
if not fname:
   fname = "mbox-short.txt"

with open(fname) as fin:
    items = (line.split()[1] for line in fin if line.startswith("From "))
    counts = Counter(items)
print counts
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I'm trying to finish the work by using the methods and functions that the prof told me to use. T-T. I need to understand the basics before I get to the more intermediate solutions